# Before that I faced + - the same problem helped as List<dynamic>, but it doesn't help in this case

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I'm trying to to call HTTP API to show the information of products

```
 Future<void> getProblem() async {
    final responce = await dio.get('https://localhost:7050/api/Problem/1',
        options: Options(
          headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
        ));
    final problemsJsonList = responce.data as List<dynamic>;
    final problem =
    problemsJsonList.map((e) => ProblemWithCommentModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    print(problem);

  }
```

its used models

````
part 'ProblemWithCommentModel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ProblemWithCommentModel
{
  final String userName;
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String name;
  final String about;
  final String date;

  List<Comments> comments;

  ProblemWithCommentModel({
    required this.userName,
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.name,
    required this.about,
    required this.comments,
    required this.date,


  });






  factory ProblemWithCommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ProblemWithCommentModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProblemWithCommentModelToJson(this);



ProblemWithCommentModel _$ProblemWithCommentModelFromJson(
        Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    ProblemWithCommentModel(
      userName: json['userName'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      about: json['about'] as String,
      comments: (json['comments'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => Comments.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
      date: json['date'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$ProblemWithCommentModelToJson(
        ProblemWithCommentModel instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'userName': instance.userName,
      'id': instance.id,
      'userId': instance.userId,
      'name': instance.name,
      'about': instance.about,
      'date': instance.date,
      'comments': instance.comments,
    };



}```



```

class Comments
{
  final String userName;
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final int problemId;
  final String about;
  final String date;


  Comments({
    required this.userName,
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.problemId,
    required this.about,
    required this.date,
});

  factory Comments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CommentsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CommentsToJson(this);




part of 'Comments.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Comments _$CommentsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Comments(
      userName: json['userName'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      problemId: json['problemId'] as int,
      about: json['about'] as String,
      date: json['date'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$CommentsToJson(Comments instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'userName': instance.userName,
      'id': instance.id,
      'userId': instance.userId,
      'problemId': instance.problemId,
      'about': instance.about,
      'date': instance.date,
    };

}```
`



Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 99:3        castError
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 452:10  cast
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 635:14     as_C
packages/auth/page_of_problem.dart 25:44                                                                                       getProblem
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 557:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 47:12                                         complete
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 613:44                                             onValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                                         callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15               <fn>





I need list of PromlemWitchComments
````

Answer (score 0):

```
responce.data as List<dynamic>;
```

responce.data is not from type List, it's a Map. Remove the casting to List.

Comment: Doesn't work, already tried((((((

Comment: What error do you get? Need more information to help out :D